# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizablePhantomReference

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm working on Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1

I'm having this error when I try to compile the project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.common.base.FinalizablePhantomReference found in modules jetified-google-collect-snapshot-20080530 (com.google.code.google-collections:google-collect:snapshot-20080530) and jetified-guava-28.1-android (com.google.guava:guava:28.1-android)
```

Is simple annoying, I not able to recognize which exactly generate the error (The duplicate class).

Please let me know if you have any clue or if you have had the same problem before and know how to solve it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following implementation in the app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:17.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Comment: No, not working but thanks.